# Convergeance and Lebesgue Integral exercise

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Can you help me formally prove that $f_n:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$,$f_n=n\chi_{[\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n}]}$ $\forall n\in\mathbb N$ converges pointwise to $f\equiv 0$ and that every $f_n$ is Lebesgue integrable?

It is not a homework,I am solving exercises for my tomorrow's measure theory exam.I thank you all in advance !

Comment: Draw the graphs. You should find the problem straightforward.

Comment: I can see it converges to 0,but I don't know how to strictly state it using the p.w convergeance definition.

Comment: Fix $x>0$. Choose $n$ with $2/n<x$. What's the value of $f_m(x)$ for $m\ge n$?

Comment: It's not monotone. Moreover, $\int f_n=1$ for any $n$, while $\int f=0$; so, $\int f_n\not\rightarrow\int f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix any $x\in\mathbb{R}$. If $x> 0$, then there exists $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$ $x\notin[\frac{1}{n}, \frac{2}{n}]$ (because $\frac{2}{n} < x$) and thus $f_n(x)=0$. . And if $x \leq 0$, $f_n(x)=0$ for all $n$ anyway, as the support of $f_n$ is in $(0,\infty)$.

So for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $f_n(x) \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$; hence $(f_n)_n$ converges pointwise to $\bar{0}$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Further, for any fixed $n$, $f_n$ is a simple function, and is thus Lebesgue integrable because $\mathbf{1}_{[\frac{1}{n}, \frac{2}{n}]}$ is measurable and has finite measure.

Comment: Thank you very much ! You were very helpfull !